# laptop monitor for desktop computer

Tags: multiple-monitors

i do not have a monitor for my desktop, but I need to use it for my sewing software, this is not for dual monitors. I only want my laptop for a monitor to use my desktop items. I bought the dell desktop in 2003. Ha, this is why I bought a laptop. but the desktop version is the only way to use my sewing machine software.

thank,
Vickie

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the laptop to access the sewing software on your desktop?  Remotely?

Comment: Monitors are cheap. Why not just buy one for the desktop computer?

Comment: You can not use a laptop as a monitor for a desktop without taking it apart and repurposing it. Laptops only support video output, not input.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to remotely access your desktop from another device. The easiest way to do that is to use one of the following.

- Windows Remote Desktop Connection (RDP)
- TeamViewer
- VNC

Google for one of the above, along the words "How to" and your operating systems. You should find a tutorial as the steps to set this up depends on what your operating system is on both your Dell and your laptop.

Comment: I was just writing the same answer, except that I was going to add that if the desktop has a baseband video monitor output, you could use a video capture device on the laptop. This would give the fastest response.

Comment: @AFH Your answer would've been much cooler :)  from the OP's question, I sense that may have gone straight over their head ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need a VGA capture device (frame grabber) that has USB output. There are plenty of VGA to USB converters, but based on a quick Google search it appears that the only VGA frame grabber with USB output is [this one from Epiphan](http://www.epiphan.com/products/frame-grabbers/vga2usb/)*. To use it, you'd connect a VGA cable from the desktop computer to the device, and a USB cable from the device to the laptop. The VGA output from the desktop would be displayed by software provided by Epiphan (bundled with the device), which you'd install on the laptop.

Whether this is a *practical* solution is questionable, considering that this little gadget sells for $300. Low-end brand new 19" LCD monitors go for under $100 these days, and if you want to look at used 17" monitors (which presumably would give you a display as large as or larger than your laptop), they can easily be had for under $50. So, if you're looking to save money on buying a monitor, this isn't going to do it. On the other hand, if space and/or portability are more important considerations, then this will do what you want.

Alternatively, you can get a VGA to AV frame grabber and a USB "TV Tuner" (AV input device). Make sure the two devices have at least one AV connection type in common (composite aka RCA, component, or S-Video aka Y/C). You'd wire the devices as follows:

1. Connect the desktop's VGA output to the frame grabber's VGA input.
2. Connect the frame grabber's AV output to the tuner's AV input.
3. Connect the tuner's USB output to the laptop.

This is a more complicated solution, but there are a lot more of both kinds of devices out there, so it's a more likely that you'd be able to find cheap used ones.

You can use remote control software, as suggested in a prior answer, but the catch there is that you'd have to install client software on the desktop, so you'd need to be able to access the desktop's OS before you can have this solution in place. You'd either need to have temporary use of a monitor for the desktop, or use command line tools to install the client remotely. You'd also need to network the computers together (using a hub, switch, wireless LAN, or crossover cable).

---

<sub>* I have absolutely no connection whatsoever with Epiphan, and I welcome you to do your own search to see if you can find something cheaper, but as far as I can see that's the only such device out there as of this writing.</sub>

Comment: If you go with buying a cheap monitor instead, I suggest going to your local Goodwill, they often have monitors in good shape that will get the job done.